# Write system call C , fills file with garbage

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am facing some issues when trying to filter specific words from a file, and write them into a new file.
What I am trying to do is writing only words that comes after '&' until the first digit.

For example (This is the content of the file I am reading from):

```
& some 12 test1 test2
$ thisword 4 no no no no
```

For the above input , I want to write into a new file the words **some** and **thisword** only.

My code is working but , instead of printing only those words , it is printing garbage as well.

```
int main (argc,argv)
     int argc;
     char *argv[];
{
    int inpfd,outpfd,n;
    int i=0;
    char tmp[2],buff[BUFFSIZE];    //This is our buffer

    //Open the output file of ispell
    inpfd = open("outputfile.txt",O_RDONLY);

    //Check if open command failed
    if(inpfd == -1) {
        printf("Failed to open file");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Here we are reading from output file
    read(inpfd,buff,999);
    buff[999] = '\0';
    close(inpfd);

    outpfd = open("w.txt",O_WRONLY);

    if(outpfd == -1) {       
        printf("Cannot open file for writing!");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Looping over the Buffer
    for (i=0; i <BUFFSIZE;  i++) {
        printf("This is the char : %c \n",buff[i]);
        if(buff[i] == '&') {
            i++;
            while( !(isdigit(buff[i])) ) {   //Write into output file
                                             //As long as we didnt reach
                tmp[0] = buff[i];      // To the digit                 
                write(outpfd,tmp,1);
                i++;
            }
            write(outpfd,"\n",1);  //Moving to the next line
        }
    }
    close(outpfd);

    return 0;
}
```

This the output of the file after the writing (I am pasting only small part of the garbage):

```
some
thisword 
^@^@^@<FD>^?^@^@<80><B2>-<AD><FD>^?^@^@<B0>
<B0>be^@^@^@^@೵[^X^?^@^@^@<B4>-<AD><FD>^?^@^@s^X<F0>[^X^?^@^@^@<FF>^@^@^@^@^@^@
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@/
```

I have no idea what is this garbage , can someone please assist?

Comment: Your syntax for the main declaration is 30+ years old.  (putting the argument types between the function name and body) We strongly recommend you write in modern C.

Comment: Your input file (`inpfd`) is named `outputfile.txt`? And opened ReadOnly?  Don't you think that is a bit obtuse?

Comment: You have no moral right to understand why your program is failing if you make no attempt to check the error reporting that your system calls are trying to give you.

Comment: @abelenky It's the output from another program (`ispell`).

Comment: ^ That's right , sorry if this is confusing

Comment: @PaulGriffiths , I tried but didn't figure it out yet.

Comment: How does the word: `thisword` become part of the desired selected words?  it does not follow a `&`?

Comment: any error messages should be written to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  and should also write the message related to `errno` when a system function returns an error indication.  A easy way to do that is with: `perror()`  for example, this line: `printf("Failed to open file");` should be replaced with something like: `perror("open for input file failed");`

Comment: regarding these two lines: `read(inpfd,buff,999);
    buff[999] = '\0';`  1) there is nothing in the code to assure that the length of `buf[]` is >= 999.   However, there is proof that the length of `buf[]` is BUFFSIZE. 2) there is nothing in the code to assure that the number of bytes read is 999.   3) when calling the function: `read()`, should always check the returned value for errors and to determine the number of bytes actually read.  Suggest: `ssize_t numBytesRead = read(inpfd,buff, BUFFSIZE-1);
    buff[ numBytesRead ] = '\0'`;

Comment: regarding this line: `for (i=0; i <BUFFSIZE;  i++) {`  There is nothing in the code to assure the number of bytes available to scan is `BUFFSIZE.  (see my prior comment)  Suggest: `for (i=0; buff[i];  i++) {`, which will stop looping when the '\0' byte is encountered.

Comment: regarding these two lines: `tmp[0] = buff[i];      // To the digit                 
                write(outpfd,tmp,1);`   1) this will output other characters other than the word of interest, for instance leading/trailing spaces, etc. (per the question, this may be ok) 2) if the word were the last characters in the file, then this would output the trash beyond the end of the actual data.  3) the array `tmp[]` is not actually needed.  Suggest: `while( buff[i] && !isdigit(buff[i] ) ) {  write( outpfd, buff[i] ); i++; }

Comment: regarding this line: `write(outpfd,"\n",1);`   a "\n" is not necessarily only a single byte (for instance, on windows it is two bytes)  Suggest: `write(outpfd,"\n", sizeof( "\n" ));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in this code

```
read(inpfd,buff,999);
buff[999] = '\0';
close(inpfd);
```

where you are ignoring the actual length of what you are reading

You should at least use the length of data actually read -- like this

```
int len = read(inpfd,buff,999);
buff[len] = '\0';
close(inpfd);
```

However note that the above have it own issues, as read does not always return everything in one go and can terminate early for interrupts etc etc, but that is beyond the scope of this question.   For very simple apps, you may just get away with the simple modification.

Now after null terminating knowing the actual length of the file from the result of read, you also need to fix your loop -- the first step would be to have your outer loop only looking at the data that you read, so

So instead

```
 for (i=0; i <BUFFSIZE;  i++) {
```

use the actual length;

```
 for (i=0; i <len;  i++) {
```

Your code inside the loop contains several issues as well, loop termination for one, that you will have to fix as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. this didn't solve my problem , is there anything else I can do? I do not know the number of characters in the file I am reading from

Comment: Well -- you also need to fix your loop, since that still runs to BUFFSIZE -- I updated the answer with that -- but there are pleanty more programming issues that you will have to fix as well to get the functionality that you described -- but those you should try to solve singlestep through the program using a debugger (gdb if you are on linux)

Comment: `read()`  returns `ssize_t` not `int` and it also very well may fail.

Answer (score 2):

You are looping over the entire size of your buffer, or 999 items.

```
for (i=0; i <BUFFSIZE;  i++) {
```

The input file is almost certainly shorter than 999 items. So once you're done processing the supplied input, you're just processing garbage until your counter reaches 999!

Comment: He didn't post the definition of `BUFSIZE`, it might be even longer than `999`.

Comment: BUFFSIZE is 1000 , I understand that it is processing garbage but why is it writing the garbage to the output file?